# NumPy setup install doesn't work for IronPython

Tags: numpy, scipy, ironpython

I'm currently working on a python integration project for a c# application. Everything I need between IronPython and C# was working, now my next step is to implement numpy and scipy for the script usage.

I have already installed them on my computer with ironpkg over the following link: http://code.enthought.com/.iron/eggs/index.html

If I'm right, the ironpkg manager only unpacked numpy and scipy libraries to the lib/site-packages folder so there was no installation of the libraries for real. How it seems the explicit installation of the NumPy and SciPy setup is necessary for being able to work with it.

My first step is to install NumPy and I already had some struggle with it.

What I have been already trying in the root dir of numpy:

```
pip install setup.py
```

where I get 5 of these connection attempt logs:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000000000275>
```

I also tried to install numpy over this command:

```
pip install numpy
```

But it responds me with the same connection fail warnings like on the first command, which is really strange.

I use IronPython version 2.7.11 2.7.11.0 on .NET 4.0.30319.42000

If you have already had a similar situation like this or know the solution I would really appreciate any help.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. My current company where I'm doing an internship uses proxy and pip can't connect to the servers without using it in the command.

The usage is like following:

```
pip install --proxy="server:port" packagexyz
```

You have to add your proxy server, port and replace the packagexyz with your package you need to install.